# php.exe is having some issues

Tags: php

I am issuing command line php to run a php script but suddenly there is nothing output after I try

```
php function.php parameters
```

Nothing is displayed.

What is going on ?

```
C:>php function.php 111 [Enter]
C:>

<?php
   function main($argc, $argv)
   {
      if($argc!=2) 
      {
        echo "wrong parameters";
        return;
      }
      //do it 
    }
?>
```

I try `php function.php`
it doesn't print the echo statement,

Comment: We need some more information. For example, what's in `function.php`?

Comment: it's simple as computing 3+3=6, in my case 111+111=222. It used to work fine, I didn't correct anything in the script. I have downloaded new PHP windows installer and run the same command line but things are just the same.

Comment: can you show the script?

Answer (score 5):

Your script is just defining a function named `main`. PHP does not have a *function* that it automatically executes; it just starts executing the *script*. Either get rid of the function definition or call `main` yourself. For example:

```
<?php
if($argc == 3) {
    echo $argv[1] + $argv[2], "\n";
}else{
    echo "Two parameters are required.\n";
}
```